# Python Error while trying to run a script: NameError: name 'long' is not defined

Tags: python

I am very new to coding in general and I have a task to try and use this script that I found to convert some data files I have to CSV format. I am using a this code based on what I read in the code it self.

```
python mavlogdump.py flightdata.bin -f --format "csv"
```

The method I use to run this code is that I have mavlogdump.py and flightdata.bin in the same folder. I point the CMD to that folder and use the line above to try and execute the script. However no matter what I have tried I get an error of:

```
NameError: name 'long' is not defined. line 32
```

I looked at line 32 and tried to include it in my script execute, however, I still had no luck. The script I am trying to run is in this github.

```
https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink/blob/7b0d51cca7e75b3cf84f5dbb74e76f727816e50d/tools/mavlogdump.py
```

Comment: So you are running some script you found on the Internet, and it does not work? And you would like someone to fix it for you? I don't think you'll find that on SO.

Comment: @zvone I am not asking someone to fix it for me. Just asking for some direction.

Comment: What I meant was that this kind of quesition is off-topic here. SO is for specific programming questions: if you have a code snippet which does not work, SO is the right place to ask why it does not do what you expect. Questions asking about why a downloaded application does not work when you run it are not programming questions at all. For some tools, it makes sense to ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).